# Does Mercurial's HGRCPATH override user level .hgrc or installation level config file?

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg

My understanding: Mercurial has three levels of config files: one shared by all users (installation level), an overriding one for each user (user level) and an overriding one for each repository (repo level).

The HGRCPATH environment variable appears to override the second level, the one found in the *`users/<user`>* directory in Windows.

However in TortoiseHG's settings screen, it refers to (and allows direct edit of) the user level config file in the *`users/<user`>* directory, even when overridden by HGRCPATH. Quick experimentation has shown that TortoiseHG indeed uses the one set by HGRCPATH, not the one it indicates.

Is this a bug with Tortoise or is my understanding of HGRCPATH flawed?

Comment: TortoiseHG 2.02, Mercurial 1.8.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The description in the Mercurial manpage makes it sound like if HGRCPATH is set then both the system-wide file (`/etc/mercurial/hgrc` on linux) and per-user file are ignored, but that the `$(hg root)/.hg/hgrc` file is still consulted.  That's been my experience outside of tortoisehg.

I wouldn't expect the tortoisehg GUI to not-show the hgrc commands its not invoking, just to not take in their settings.  Is that what you're seeing?

http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hg.1.html

Comment: TortoiseHG's workbench has a settings page which gives a gui front end to the user .hgrc file, and allows one to click a button to edit it manually. If I wipe out the contents of the user .hgrc file, Tortoise will (for instance) not allow me to pick my visual diff tool from the menu. However, if I go to do a visual diff in the workbench, it still calls my custom diff tool, because it's still defined in my .hgrc file I have sitting at HGRCPATH.

Comment: Hence TortoiseHG's user setting screen appears to have zero effect if HGRCPATH is used.

Comment: I guess that's what I'd expect.  That GUI page (and, again, I've never used it) edits your user settings, and HGRCPATH tells Mercurial to ignore your user settings.  Makes sense to me.

Comment: I would agree if HGRCPATH's purpose was to ignore user settings, but I'm seeing it more for the purpose of relocating your user settings (I hate having things in the users dir). HGRCPATH is still per user (if set as a user environment variable). It's no big deal, it just caused a bit of confusion for me when I was editing my settings via Tortoise and nothing was happening. Thanks for your thoughts.

Comment: The point of HGRCPATH *is* to ignore user settings.  You might have set it per user, but the more common use is doing it per-invocation.  It was added so that people writing scripts could do so knowing that whatever might be in place on the system and user hgrc files wasn't going to break their script.  It's not a part of tortoise; it's part of mercurial.  If you want to move your hgrc elsewhere you can put a single `%include` like in your `~/.hgrc` that includes something else, but it will still confuse the GUI layer.

Comment: I can see both interpretations. Appreciate your time Ry4an.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, this must be a flaw in TortoiseHg. The [`hg help environment`](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hg.1.html#environment) help text says that `HGRCPATH` is used to override the default search path for configuration files. This includes `~/.hgrc` and lets you quickly disable your user settings:

```
$ HGRCPATH= hg log  # <- only read .hg/hgrc, ignore all other config files
```

You cannot make Mercurial skip reading `.hg/hgrc`.